# Jquery functions not linked correctly? Why can'y my <script> section run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying to create a simple "squad builder", basically just creating a list as different buttons are clicked. I noticed Jquery was not working, although it has been linked to in the  section. I can't even access basic animations. What is going on in here?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<head>

    <title>Squad Builder</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").addClass("animated bounce");

  });

</script>

<style type="text/css">

    #player-box {

        background-color: red;
        height: 500px;
        width: 130px;
    }

    #squad-box {

        background-color: red;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div class = "row container-fluid">
    <div id = "player-box" class =  "col-md-6">

        <ul id = "player-list">

            <li><button class = "player-btn btn">Player1</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id = "squad-box" class = "col-md-6">

        <ul id = "squad-list">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: `animated bounce` `<---` you're talking about [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)?

Comment: Your script tag runs before DOM ready. Put your `script` tag just before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: add http: to code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js  and it will work

Comment: put your SCRIPT block inside the HEAD section

Comment: @KKK OP is using jQuery's document ready callback so no need to put script at end. AlenToma OP's use of having `//` at the front instead of the protocol is fine as the browser will then use whatever protocol the current page is on

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am still not seeing my jQuery code run, even after including animate.css. Can you tell what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, probably is only missing the **animate.css** assets:

[animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").addClass("animated bounce");
});
```

```css
#player-box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 130px;
}

#squad-box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="row container-fluid">
  <div id="player-box" class="col-md-6">
    <ul id="player-list">
      <li><button class="player-btn btn">Player1</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="squad-box" class="col-md-6">
    <ul id="squad-list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```